# how to make images show like slide show with handler timer?

Tags: android

if i use `handler` i can delay an image to be visible/invisible with specific time.
like that:

```
imageuser.setImageBitmap(bitmapObject);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imageuser.setImageBitmap(null);
                }
            }, 5000);
```

---

**Suppose** that i have three images (img1, img2, img3)
and

i want to show "img1" firstly for 5 seconds then it will be invisible

then img2 visible for 5 seconds then it will be invisible

then img3 visible for 5 seconds then it will be invisible

How to do that ?
please answer me in details :) thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need an int variable, which present the current state and change images visibilites according. Something like this

```
    int i = 1;
    android.os.Handler h = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            switch (++i){
                case 1:
                    img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    img3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    img1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    img3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    i = 0;
                    img1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    img3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
            // Run again in 5s.
            h.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };
    h.postDelayed(r, 5000)
```

Also make sure that handler, runnable and int are a global variables, so you have access to them inside the runnable.